# Alternative for Assembly.LoadFile, Assembly.LoadFrom and Assembly.Load?

Tags: c#, dll, .net-core

I have two problems with a minimal, reproducible example that has three project targeting .NET Core 3.1. But I also want to target **.NET Standard 2.0**.

The example is for an application that needs to load an assembly in run time and makes use of the provided assembly.

The assembly that is loaded references another project, which in turn makes use of a NuGet package.

## Code

- project Host is a Console Application that has no project references and no package references. It contains the file Program.cs:

```csharp
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var featurePath = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(@"..\..\..\..\Feature\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\Feature.dll");
        var featureAssembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFile(featurePath);
        var featureType = featureAssembly.GetType("SomeFeature");
        var featureInstance = System.Activator.CreateInstance(featureType);
        featureType.InvokeMember("PrintText",
            System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, featureInstance, new object[0]);
    }
}
```

- project Feature is a Class Library that has a ProjectReference for `..\Subfeature\Subfeature.csproj` and contains the file SomeFeature.cs:

```csharp
public class SomeFeature
{
    public void PrintText()
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine(new SomeSubfeature().GetText());
    }
}
```

- project Subfeature is a Class Library that has a PackageReference for `Newtonsoft.Json` and contains the file SomeSubfeature.cs:

```csharp
public class SomeSubfeature
{
    public string GetText()
    {
        return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject("Some Text");
    }
}
```

## Solved Problems

- The first solved problem is because the consumed assemblies reference another project and/or make use of packages. `Assembly.LoadFrom` only loads the requested assembly. The referenced project's assembly and packages are not loaded. This results in a FileNotFoundException because Subfeature could not be found.
   
  I could solve this problem by (1) replacing `Assembly.LoadFile(featurePath)` with `Assembly.LoadFrom(featurePath)` so other required DLLs in the same directory can also be loaded. And (2) by making package DLLs that are only copied to the same directory during publish also get copied during build, by adding into Feature.csproj `<PropertyGroup><CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>true</CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies></PropertyGroup>`.
- The second solved problem is that the application locks the DLLs while they are loaded. This prevents me from deploying newer versions of the DLL's while the application is still running. It makes releasing newer versions cumbersome, when let's say, the application is part of an IIS hosted application. .NET Core no longer supports loading a shadow copy of a DLL.
   
  I could solve this problem by (1) replacing `Assembly.LoadFile(featurePath)` into `Assembly.Load(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(featurePath))` so required DLLs are loaded from bytes that are read before loading. And (2) having a filewatcher reload the application if something happens with a DLL file in its directory.

## Final Problem

The solution to the first problem is not compatible with the solution to the second problem. `Assembly.LoadFrom` fixes my first problem. `Assembly.Load` fixes my second problem. But I haven't found an alternative for `Assembly.LoadFile` that fixes both problems at the same time.

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/Documentation/design-docs/unloadability.md

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? I read your post 5 times and did not get any information what is your task and problems.

Comment: @DominicJonas given the example application above, I want to have .net standard 2.0 way of loading the Feature assembly in a manner that it will be able to resolve its dependencies (SubFeature and Newtonsoft) and not keep the loaded assemblies locked.

Comment: When a dll is loaded it is normally loaded as with Share_Delete flag. That enables you to rename locked dlls. To replace running assemblies all you need to do is to rename them and then copy the new ones. Have you tried that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `AssemblyResolve` event handler to `AppDomain.CurrentDomain` and handle assembly loading as you do with reading all bytes.

```
        const string location = @"..\..\..\..\Dependency\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var domain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
            domain.AssemblyResolve += Domain_AssemblyResolve;
            var type = Type.GetType("Dependency.DependentClass,Dependency, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null");
            var obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
            Console.WriteLine(obj.ToString());     
        }

        private static Assembly Domain_AssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
        {
            var dll = $"{args.Name.Split(",")[0]}.dll";
            var path = Path.Combine(location, dll);
            var asm = Assembly.Load(File.ReadAllBytes(path));
            return asm;
        }
```

A side note: You need to provide full name for type else it will throw error. Like: `"Dependency.DependentClass"`

Dependency assembly has 2 dependencies one is `Newtonsoft.Json` NuGet package, the other one is another project. `Bar` class resides in another project.

```
 public class DependentClass
    {
        public int MyProperty { get; set; }

        public string AnotherProperty { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new Bar());
        }
    }
```

**EDIT:** After the downvote, I looked up the above solution again and although it works it seems more likely a `. net Framework` kind of a solution rather than a `.net Core`
So a more `. net Core` like solution is  to use a [`AssemblyLoadContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/assembly/unloadability).

> Define a custom assembly load context.

```
public class CustomLoadContext : AssemblyLoadContext
    {
        private readonly AssemblyDependencyResolver resolver;

        public CustomLoadContext(string mainAssemblyToLoadPath) : base(isCollectible: true)
        {
            resolver = new AssemblyDependencyResolver(mainAssemblyToLoadPath);
        }


        protected override Assembly Load(AssemblyName name)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Resolving : {0}",name.FullName);
            var assemblyPath = resolver.ResolveAssemblyToPath(name);
            if (assemblyPath != null)
            {
                return Assembly.Load(File.ReadAllBytes(assemblyPath));
            }

            return Assembly.Load(name);
        }
    }
```

> Load your assembly and let the custom loader context to  load it's dependencies.

```
        const string location = @"..\..\..\..\Dependency\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var fullPath = Path.GetFullPath(location + "Dependency.dll");
            var clx = new CustomLoadContext(fullPath); // initialize custom context
            var asm = clx.LoadFromStream(new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(fullPath))); // load your desired assembly
            var ins = asm.CreateInstance("Dependency.DependentClass");  
            Console.WriteLine(ins.ToString());
       
        }
```

Comment: So I tried your solution, and `resolver` fails to load System.Runtime. `assemblyPath` becomes null, and a System.IO.FileLoadException is thrown. `'Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.2.2.0, ...` I'm not sure why it's trying to resolve and load System.Runtime though.

Comment: @nl-x Try returning null instead `Assembly.Load(name)`. If you want i can share a github repo working in my local env.

Comment: Sorry, I think I didn't implement the if-condition correct. I think it's working now. Thanks to a colleague I already was pretty far this direction, even using AssemblyLoadContext. But your addition of using AssemblyDependencyResolver is a real eye opener.

Comment: Do you know if there is a .net standard 2.0 version of AssemblyDependencyResolver ? I just noticed it indeed only exists in .net core 3.1, which is indeed the one in my example projects. But I just realized I need to target .net standard 2.0.

Comment: @nl-x I'm afraid there is no .net standard version that includes .net core 3.1 support. So if you want to support .net standard you have to stick with `AppDomain` solution even it is uglier.

Comment: Do you have an example of how to use AppDomain with loading dll's without locking them, AND can resolve dependencies? I don't care if it's uglier.

Comment: @nl-x it's already in the answer. The part before the edit is another solution.

Comment: ah, you mean in combination with `<CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>`, so all dll's end up in the output directory? Because in case of Nugets, their location needs to be resolved. `<CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>` proves to be a bit hacky. I will try this today nonetheless.

Comment: and one more question: can you tell me why you prefer CreateInstanceAndUnwrap over Activator? What's the difference in your opinion?

Comment: @nl-x Actually under the hood `AppDomain` uses `Activator` class for creating an instance. But I realized that method signature creates an `ObjectHandle` which is normally used for cross-appdomain object access or remoting. So I changed the previous example to create an instance from type. For resolving nuget packages I might suggest using `Nuget` v3 API to download necessary packages but I don't think it would be less hacky than using `<CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>`.